# C# DataGridRow.Rows Selects the new row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a simple function in my program that selects the current cell, then it (FillsDown) copies the current cell into ALL the cells below it.

However my simple function places the value in the Row at the bottom which is the new row and I do not want the value to be populated here.

Heres the current code. (Where COLINDEX is just the column im referring to in my grid)

```
            string replacestring = row.Cells[COLINDEX].Value.ToString();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid1.Rows)
            {

                if (row.Index > startrow)
                {
                    row.Cells[COLINDEX].Value = replacestring;
                }
            }
```

Is there a simeple method/property I can check against so I dont accidently populate the last row ?
My example  below uses a fake property (.`Exist`)

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid1.Rows)
            {

                if ((row.Index > startrow) && row.Exist)
                {
                    row.Cells[COLINDEX].Value = replacestring;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridViewRow has a property called [IsNewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.isnewrow.aspx)

And try to walk the Rows collection using the index

```
        for(int x = startRow + 1; x < dataGrid1.Rows.Count; x++) 
        { 
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGrid1.Rows[x];
            if (row.IsNewRow == false) 
            { 
                row.Cells[COLINDEX].Value = replacestring; 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: great, ill try it, I was going to do something like check row.Index == row.Rows.Count, but it doesnt sound robust because I could later turn the feature off to allow new rows